# selecting td from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following Html stirng stored in a JS variable:

```
<td>
  <input onclick="Clicked(this);" type="radio" name="mmBox" id="mmBox">
</td>
<td>First Cell</td>
<td>2nd TD</td>
<td>3rd TD</td>
<td>4th TD</td>
<td>5th TD</td>
<td></td>
```

I depending on need I need to select 2nd, 3rd and 4th `<td>`

I have tried the following but it do not return anything:

```
console.log("6 " + $(selectedRow).wrap("<tr></tr>").children("td:nth-child(2)").html());
```

or

```
console.log("6 " + $(selectedRow).find("td:eq(2)").text());
```

Even with `.find` and `.select` methods as well but it do not return anything.

Please help me, I want to query `<td>` and value inside it

Comment: What's the need? You cannot use `.find()` here. You need to use `.nextAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `selectedRow` variable contains the html string that you have posted, you should use the `.filter` method instead of the `.find`:

```
$(selectedRow).filter(":eq(2)").text();
```

Or by using the `.eq` method:

```
$(selectedRow).eq(1).text();
```

Note that `.eq` is zero-based so 1 selects the second element in the set.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold that's not accurate, find will return a collection of ***descendants***

Answer (score 2):

The [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method wrap each `td` with separate `tr` element, I think you need a single `tr` which wraps all the element for that use [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll) method. Although use  [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method since you need filter out `td` from the jQuery element and not from its children. Actually wrapping with `tr` is completely unnecessary if you just want to fetch the content.

```js
var selectedRow = '<td><input onclick="Clicked(this);" type="radio" name="mmBox" id="mmBox"></td><td>First Cell</td><td>2nd TD</td><td>3rd TD</td><td>4th TD</td><td>5th TD</td><td></td>';
console.log("6 " + $(selectedRow).wrapAll("<tr></tr>").filter("td:nth-child(2)").html());
// by removing code which wraps the elements
console.log("6 " + $(selectedRow).filter("td:nth-child(2)").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it the other way around....create a row element first and set the cells in that row then you can use `find` on the row object

```
var $row = $('<tr>').html(selectedRow);
console.log("6 " + $row.find("td:eq(2)").text());
```